# double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: c, string, pointers

This code reads a null terminated string from a file (file containing null terminated strings & should provide index to wanted string).

Error:

```
*** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x090a4a80 ***
Aborted
```

Code:

```
char *tmp_realloc=NULL;
char *sstring=NULL;
int i=1;

/*Set file pointer to point string*/
fseek(fh,index,SEEK_SET);

sstring=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
   if(sstring == NULL)
        return NULL;

tmp_realloc=sstring;

while( (*(sstring+i-1)=(char)fgetc((FILE*)fh)) != 0x0 ) {
    /*reallocate more memory*/
     tmp_realloc=(char*)realloc((char*)sstring,++i);

     /*if not same address copy old to new & set old to point new*/
      if(tmp_realloc != sstring){
          strcpy((char*)tmp_realloc,(char*)sstring);
          free(sstring);
          sstring=tmp_realloc;
      }
}
```

Could you tell me what pointer is causing this issue (& for what reason) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the part

```
/*if not same address copy old to new & set old to point new*/
 if(tmp_realloc != sstring){
     strcpy((char*)tmp_realloc,(char*)sstring);
     free(sstring);
     sstring=tmp_realloc;
 }
```

This is almost (something like `memcpy()` will be used instead of `strcpy()`) exactly what `realloc()` will do for you if it succeeds. Instead of that, insert error checking and simply assign `tmp_realloc` to `sstring` if no error is found.

Also casting `char*` to `char*` seems completely useless, so why not remove these casts?

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now. So i understand that the error comes from the fact that i did `free(sstring)` which has already been done by `realloc` so memory freeing is been done twice on the same pointer?